# ADD COLUMNS from for loop with SQLite3

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, for-loop

I am new to SQL, trying to build an app in Python/Tkinter where the user can enter custom "parameters" for a database (that become SQL Columns). The first column is a datetime and all subsequent columns are user created. Here is my code:

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE records (dt datetime)")

for record in listOfRecords:
    c.execute("ALTER TABLE records ADD (?) integer;", (record))
```

This produces error: `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error`

I have also tried the "faux-tuple" format with:

```
for record in listOfRecords:
    c.execute("ALTER TABLE records ADD (?,) integer;", (record,))
```

The same error occurs. Sorry for the noob question, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try to use `?` without the `()`. `ALTER TABLE records ADD ? integer;`.

Comment: *where the user can enter custom "parameters" for a database (that become SQL Columns)* ... consider avoiding such a design. Users should not adjust schema of database objects on the fly via an app. Look into appending rows or structure app to guide user behavior. Yes, I know it's just SQLite today but tomorrow it may be an enterprise server like Postgres.

Comment: @Parfait it is a "personal health" app where users will be creating the DB based on the symptoms & medications they have most frequently as parameters, and then entries will be values of those parameters. How would this be best structured?

Comment: You may have just answered it. Create a *symptoms* and *medications* table with an open-ended text or number field for parameters. Then have app append new rows by *user_id*. and datetime instead of new columns. In fact, querying would be easier since you will search for values instead of optional, non-standard column names requiring messy concatenation in `SELECT` clause. Long tables are cheaper than wide tables.

Comment: @Parfait thanks for the advice, I'll look into re-structuring with appending rows rather than columns. Currently my app is offline just using tkinter for GUI, would it still be useful to use _user_id_ in this case?

Comment: Is the question solved?